# How to call something inputted by user in the code? aws api

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, input

```
data = cd.get_cost_and_usage(TimePeriod={'Start':input("Enter Start Date in format yyyy-mm-dd:\n"),'End': input("Enter End Date in format yyyy-mm-dd:\n")}, Granularity='MONTHLY',
                             Metrics=[input('Choose any of the following metrics: AMORTIZED_COST, UNBLENDED_COST, BLENDED_COST, USAGE_QUANTITY, NET_AMORTIZED_COST\n')],
                            GroupBy=[{'Type': 'DIMENSION', 'Key': 'LINKED_ACCOUNT'}, {'Type': 'DIMENSION', 'Key':input("Enter any of the following Dimensions - SERVICE, INSTANCE_TYPE, USAGE_TYPE, RECORD_TYPE:\n")}], **kwargs)
for info in data['ResultsByTime']:
    for group in info['Groups']:
      data=(group['Keys'][0], info['TimePeriod']['Start'], group['Metrics'][] 
['Amount'], group['Keys'][1])
          print(*data, sep=", ", file=f, flush=True)
```

in the below part of the script, the [] needs to have the same input as Metrics, how do I make it so the User doesn't have to input the same thing twice? whatever they put as Metrics comes up in this as well?

```
data=(group['Keys'][0], info['TimePeriod']['Start'], group['Metrics'][] 
['Amount'], group['Keys'][1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most logical way would be to extract the metric `input` along with the other inputs, and then re-use it.

For example:

```
metric_chosen = input('Choose any of the following metrics: AMORTIZED_COST, UNBLENDED_COST, BLENDED_COST, USAGE_QUANTITY, NET_AMORTIZED_COST\n')

date_start = input("Enter Start Date in format yyyy-mm-dd:\n")

date_end = input("Enter End Date in format yyyy-mm-dd:\n")

dimension_chosen = input("Enter any of the following Dimensions - SERVICE, INSTANCE_TYPE, USAGE_TYPE, RECORD_TYPE:\n")

data = cd.get_cost_and_usage(
    TimePeriod={
        'Start': date_start,
        'End': date_end
    }, 
    Granularity='MONTHLY',  
    Metrics=[metric_chosen],
    GroupBy=[
        {'Type': 'DIMENSION', 
         'Key': 'LINKED_ACCOUNT'
        }, 
        {'Type': 'DIMENSION', 
        'Key': dimension_chosen
        }], **kwargs)

for info in data['ResultsByTime']:
    for group in info['Groups']:
      data=(group['Keys'][0], 
            info['TimePeriod']['Start'], 
            group['Metrics'][metric_chosen]['Amount'], 
            group['Keys'][1])
      print(*data, sep=", ", file=f, flush=True)
```